# JAVA - CScan Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm currently trying to design a CScan algorithm for an elevator application.

I need some code in java which will do the following function:

```
private void MoveDown() {
    int max = requests[0];
    System.out.println("Head currently at: " + head);
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (requests[i] > max && requests[i] < head) {
            max = requests[i];
            int sum = head - max;
            System.out.println("Floor: " + max + " | Floors moved: " + sum);
        }
    }

}
```

The code is meant to calculate the closest number from the head position.
So for example, if the head is at 50 and the requests are (10, 20 30), it should go to 30 first, then 20 then 10.

However, mine goes 20, 30 and misses out 10.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your loop you are jumping to the first "floor" that is greater than max, which in this case is 10. So that is why it goes to 20 first. Your loop should look more like this.

```
int max = 0;
for(int i =0; i<requests.length;i++){
    if(requests[i]>max && requests[i] < head){
       max = requests[i];
     }
 }
 System.out.println("Floor: " + max + " | Floors moved: " + (head-max));
```

Then at the end of that loop you should print the floors moved and new floor.

Comment: That didn't work. All I need is to get to the closest number in that array that is lower than 50.